# listbox is not updated by dependency property observablecollection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

The feature I'm working on is autocomplete for keyword search. As soon as the user inputs something into search bar, the view model calls the autocomplete api with keyword parameter to get the autocomplete suggestions back and put them into a observablecollection container. This observablecollection is a dependency property, it's bound with the list box to show the autocomplete suggestions. My problem is the dependency property is populated correctly but the list box doesn't display anything. Following are some code pieces:

data binding in xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            searchBar.Focus();
            _searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel();
            DataContext = _searchViewModel;
        }
```

invoke a method in view model to call the autocomplete api:

```
private void searchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _searchViewModel.getTypeaheadListFromServer(searchBar.Text);
        }
```

dependency property in view model, it's populated successfully:

```
public ObservableCollection<TypeaheadElement> TypeaheadList
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<TypeaheadElement>)GetValue(TypeaheadListProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TypeaheadListProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TypeaheadList.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeaheadListProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TypeaheadList", typeof(ObservableCollection<TypeaheadElement>), typeof(SearchViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

data binding in xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="typeahead" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TypeaheadList}" Height="518" Margin="0,0,0,-518" SelectionChanged="typeahead_SelectionChanged">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TypeaheadElementStr}" FontSize="{StaticResource ListItemFontSize}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                         <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                                 <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ListItemFontColor}"/>
                                         </TextBlock.Foreground>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ListBox Name="typeahead" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TypeaheadList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="518" Margin="0,0,0,-518" SelectionChanged="typeahead_SelectionChanged">
```

Comment: Hi Haris, I really appreciate your help. However after adding updatesourcetrigger, I get error like this when I navigate to that page: Failed to create a 'System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger' from the text 'PropertyChanged'. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: try by changing last parameter of `DependencyProperty.Register` to   `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        null,
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)`

Comment: Hi Haris, thank you very much for your reply. I tried to use FrameworkPropertyMetadata, but it complains "FrameworkPropertyMetadata does not exist in the namespace System.Windows." However, I checked msdn doc, the FrameworkPropertyMetadata class is right under System.Windows. Any idea what's happening? Sorry for keeping asking new questions. Thanks!

Comment: I also got this error:  Failed to create a 'System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger' from the text 'PropertyChanged'  How to fix it???

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you try to implement `DependencyProperty` is this situations. `TypeaheadList` is a source of `Binding`, not a target, right? So it can be a simple property on your `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the AutoCompleteBox from the toolkit? If the list of possibilities are not large, you can pre-populate the ItemsSource of the AutoCompleteBox. If you cannot pre-populate it, you could issue an async request to the server to get all of the possibilities when the app starts. 
Here are some blogs about using the AutoCompleteBox:
http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/03/acb-in-pivot/

If that is not possible, then you can do something like the following:

Xaml:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Populating="AutoCompleteBox_Populating" />
    </Grid>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<string> {"Shawn", "steve", "Bob", "randy", "mike"};
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> People { get; set; }

    private void AutoCompleteBox_Populating(object sender, PopulatingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Have we already populated with this text?
        if(People.Any(person => person.ToLower().StartsWith(e.Parameter.ToLower()))) return;

        Completer c = new Completer();
        c.Completed += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(c_Completed);
        c.Complete(e.Parameter);
    }

    void c_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Completer c = sender as Completer;
        foreach (var name in c.Names)
        {
            People.Add(name);       
        }
    }
}

internal class Completer
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Completed;

    public IEnumerable<string> Names { get; set; }

    public void Complete(string parameter)
    {
        if (parameter.StartsWith("d"))
        {
            Names = new List<string>() { "Dick", "Dave" };
        }
        else if (parameter.StartsWith("j"))
        {
            Names = new List<string>() { "Jane", "Joe" };
        }
        OnCompleted();
    }

    protected virtual void OnCompleted()
    {
        var handler = Completed;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, I really appreciate your reply. However, I think my autocomplete api is a little different from the example. It doesn't return all the autocompletes, it returns autocompletes based on what the user types in. For example, it doesn't return all the product names, but if "ip" is sent to server, it'll return "iphone, ipod, ipad...".

Comment: (Continuing the last comment) So in this case, I think I should stick to my original way. Bind the listbox for autocomplete to a property in view model, everytime the user types in something, invoke the api to get the autocompletes back and populate the property. But my problem is the property is populated but the listbox is not updated. =(

Comment: Hi Shawn, never mind, I solved this problem. Thanks all the same!

Comment: AutoComplete behaves the same way. It filters down values as you type. The example I shoewd was a small example of how to add extra values. It was very simple, but the same concept can be used for hitting a serer. Glad you figured out your problem!