# windows phone visibility data binding in listbox itemtemplate

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a problem with control visibility in listbox itemtemplate. Following is my code to bind data to Visibility property of imagetools:AnimatedImage and Textblock in xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listSellers" ItemsSource="{Binding TagList}" SelectionChanged="listSellers_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid Margin="0,12,0,12" Height="132">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="107"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Border Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,-2,8">
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <imagetools:AnimatedImage Source="{Binding Seller.Logo, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Stretch="Uniform" Width="240" Template="{StaticResource AnimatedImageControlTemplate1}" Visibility="{Binding LogoVisibility}"/>
                                                        <TextBlock x:Name="sellerNameTxtBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Seller.Name}" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF354F59" Height="41" Visibility="{Binding Path=SellerNameVisibility}"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Border>
                                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                                                    <!--<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Seller.Name}" FontSize="24" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF354F59" Height="41"/>-->
                                                    <!--<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="amazon.com" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe WP" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF157CCC" Height="35"/>-->
                                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TotalPrice}" FontSize="21.333" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#cc4225"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" Text="{Binding Price}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF354F59"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" Text="{Binding Tax}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF354F59"/>
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" Text="{Binding Shipping}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF354F59"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Following is the declaration of the property in view model:

```
public Visibility LogoVisibility
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(LogoVisibilityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LogoVisibilityProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LogoVisibility.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LogoVisibilityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LogoVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(ProductDetailViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed));

        public Visibility  SellerNameVisibility
        {
            get { return (Visibility )GetValue(SellerNameVisibilityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SellerNameVisibilityProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SellerNameVisibility.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SellerNameVisibilityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SellerNameVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(ProductDetailViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Collapsed));
```

Following is where I set Visibility in view model:

```
foreach (Tag tag in tagArray)
                {
                    if (tag.Seller.Logo.Equals(""))
                    {
                        tag.Seller.Logo = "Images/NoImageFound.png";
                        LogoVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                        SellerNameVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LogoVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        SellerNameVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                    tag.Price = "Base: " + tag.Price;
                    if (tag.Tax == null)
                    {
                        tag.Tax = "Tax: N/A";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tag.Tax = "Tax: " + tag.Tax;
                    }
                    if (tag.Shipping == null)
                    {
                        tag.Shipping = "Ship: N/A";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tag.Shipping = "Ship: " + tag.Shipping;
                    }
                    tempTagList.Add(tag);
                }
                TagList = tempTagList;
            }
```

And here's where I set the datacontext in code behind:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            _productDetailViewModel = new ProductDetailViewModel();
            DataContext = _productDetailViewModel;
            string productTitleId = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("productTitleId", out productTitleId))
            {
                _productTitleId = productTitleId;
                _productDetailViewModel.getProductDetailFromServer(_productTitleId, "");
            }
        }
```

I also do some other data bindings in these files, all of them work. Only this Visibility binding fails. Really don't know why. =( Any ideas? Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry I didn't describe my problem clearly. What I want to do is if the logo is not empty, show the logo, hide the seller name. When the logo is empty, hide the logo, show the seller name. However, in both cases, both logo and seller name are shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your ListBox ItemsSource is bound to a collection of "Tag" objects. This means that each ListBoxItem would be bound to a "Tag" object. So, the DataTemplate you are creating has a DataContext equal to one Tag object. I do not see that LogoVisibility is on the Tag object. It looks like it is on the object that holds a reference to the tag list. Going this route, you would want the LogoVisibility and NameVisibility on the Tag object itself.

What I would suggest is to not put that logic into your model object (Tag) and instead have a ValueConverter to handle this logic.

```
    public class EmptyToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return Visibility.Collapsed;

        string val = value.ToString();

        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val) ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then change your Visibility bindings to:

```
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Seller}">
        <imagetools:AnimatedImage Source="{Binding Logo, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" 
                              Stretch="Uniform" Width="240" 
                              Template="{StaticResource AnimatedImageControlTemplate1}" 
                              Visibility="{Binding Logo, Converter={StaticResource EmptyToVis}}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="sellerNameTxtBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="24" 
               FontFamily="Segoe WP" Margin="10,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF354F59" Height="41" 
               Visibility="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource EmptyToVis}}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for your help, it works like a charm! I also posted another question related to windows phone here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749285/listbox-is-not-updated-by-dependency-property-observablecollection) I haven't got the solution yet. Can you help me have a look? If you need more info, just let me know! Thanks!